# how to solve "Cannot PUT /"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to update local database in mongodb. In my project I want to update my data here is the code.
second part is the edit part that i use to redirect my update data. It don't show any error so i can not find any problem to fix.All project in node.js, and use handelbar template , mongoose as database
:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const path = require('path')
const Idendity = require('./db/db.js')
const methodOverride = require('method-override')

app.use(methodOverride('_method'))
app.use(express.static( __dirname + "/public"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}))
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
    extname: '.hbs'
}))
app.set('view engine', '.hbs')

async function connectDB() {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Idendity', {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            useCreateIndex: true
        })
        console.log('database is connected')
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }

}
connectDB()


app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const idendity = await Idendity.find()
    const idendities = {
        data: idendity.map(element => {return{id:element._id,name:element.name,email:element.email,profession:element.profession}} )
    }
   //console.log(idendities.data)
    res.render('home', {
        ID: idendities.data,
        title: 'Contact App'
    })
})

app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const idendity = new Idendity({
        ...req.body
    })
    await idendity.save()
    res.redirect('/')
})

app.get('/edit/:id',async (req,res)=>{
    const id = req.params.id
    const idendity = await Idendity.findById(id)
    const contex = {name:idendity.name,email:idendity.email,profession:idendity.profession}
    if(idendity){
        res.render('edit',{
            idendity:contex
        })
    }else{
        res.send('404 not found')
    }

})

app.put('/edit/:id',async (req,res)=>{
    const id = req.params.id
    const value = req.body
    const newIdendity = await Idendity.findByIdAndUpdate(id,value,{ useFindAndModify:false})
    console.log(value)
    if(newIdendity){
        res.redirect(`/edit/${id}`)
    }else{
        res.send('404 not found')
    }
})

app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log('port is listening')
})


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    <div class="container">
        {{#with idendity}}
        <form action="/?_method=PUT" method="POST">
        <label for="name">name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value={{name}}><br>
        <label for="email">email</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value={{email}}><br>
        <label for="profession">profession</label> <br>
        <input type="text" name="profession" id="profession" value={{profession}}><br>
        
        <button class="btn btn-primary my-3">add</button>
        </form>{{/with}}
    <a href="/" class="btn btn-danger my-3">cancel</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can send put request to the given route because you don't have any put method attached to that route you are trying to access.
you have to have an

```
app.put("/",async(req,res)=>{
//code
})
```

or you can use

```
// this will be accessible by all HTTP methods
app.use("/",async(req,res)=>{
//code
})
```

in your code to be able to send a put request to the server.